# SAS import - stripping out header rows

Tags: import, sas

Trying to strip out page break header labels from an otherwise structured dataset. Without the headers the following would work:

```
data uk;
infile "/folders/myfolders/import/withheader.txt" truncover;
format promocode_order best10. date date9. time TIME8.  code $20. singlecode $20. name $50. order_spend best8. shipping_cost best8. country_code $2.;
informat date DDMMYY10. time TIME8. ;
input @1 promocode_order @12 date @23 time @32 order_spend @45 shipping_cost @59 code /
name 1-50 /
@1 country_code;
country_code="UK";
run;
```

But having the headers in is a problem. Is there a way I can iterate through the file prior to importing and choose which records to import. I could exclude if it starts wit a header label / is blank.

Thanks!

Comment: You should post some example data that shows the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `dummy` input statement to your data step, holding the line for a further input statement, and the check to see whether the automatic variable `_INFILE_` contains a header row. If it doesn't continue to your normal `input` statement.

E.g.

```
input @;
if _INFILE_ ne "header row string" then <original input statement>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you input some part of the line and tell from the value that it is a header that should be removed.  Also don't use a FORMAT statement to do the work of a LENGTH or ATTRIB statement.  So if your header line looks like the variable names then it might be as simple as eliminating lines that begin with 'PROMOCODE'.

```
data uk;
  infile "/folders/myfolders/import/withheader.txt" truncover;
  length promocode_order date time 8 code singlecode $20
         name $50 order_spend shipping_cost 8 country_code $2
  ;
  format date date9. time TIME8. ;
  informat date DDMMYY10. time TIME8. ;
  input @ ;
  if infile=:'PROMOCODE' or _infile_=' ' then delete ;
  input @1 promocode_order @12 date @23 time @32 order_spend @45 shipping_cost @59 code
      / @1  name 1-50
      / @1 country_code
  ;
run;
```